# How to consume from two different clusters in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have two kafka clusters say A and B, B is replica of A. I would like to consume messages from cluster B only if A is down and viceversa. Nevertheless consuming messages from  both the clusters would result in duplicate messages. So is there any way I can configure my kafka consumer to receive messages from only one cluster.

Thanks--

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So is there any way I can configure my kafka consumer to receive messages from only one cluster.

Yes: a Kafka consumer instance will always receive messages from one Kafka cluster only.  That is, there's no built-in option to use the same consumer instance for reading from 2+ clusters.  But I think you are looking for something different, see below.

> I would like to consume messages from cluster B only if A is down and viceversa. Nevertheless consuming messages from both the clusters would result in duplicate messages.

There's no built-in failover support such as "switch to cluster B if cluster A fails" in Kafka's consumer API.  If you need such behavior (as in your case), you would need to do so in your application that uses the Kafka consumer API.

For example, you could create a consumer instance to read from cluster A, monitor that instance and/or that cluster to determine whether failover to cluster B is required, and (if needed) perform the failover to B by creating another consumer instance to read from B in the event that A fails.

There are a few gotchas however that makes this failover behavior more complex than my simplified example.  One difficulty is to know which messages from cluster A have already been read when switching over to B: this is tricky because, typically, the message offsets differ between clusters so determining whether the "copy" of a message (in B) was already read (from A) is not trivial.

Note: Sometimes you can simplify such an application / such a failover logic in situations where e.g. message processing is idempotent (i.e. where duplicate messages / duplicate processing of messages will not alter the processing outcome).

Comment: I got your point, how do I deal with message offsets during the time of failover,
Note:- My message processing is not idempotent

Comment: Take a look at e.g. http://www.slideshare.net/HadoopSummit/building-largescale-stream-infrastructures-across-multiple-data-centers-with-apache-kafka by Jun Rao (Kafka committer and Confluent co-founder) as a starting point.  Note that KIP-33 (slide 32) has since been implemented in Kafka.

Comment: @MichaelG.Noll can you please clarify two thighs - a) why is offsets different between two clusters b) is it a conscious decision from client developers' not to support this scenario?

Comment: There is no synchronization between two Kafka clusters, hence there is no guarantee that offsets are the same on both sides.

Comment: If you want "offsets to be the same" on two clusters, you might want to look into Confluent's _Replicator_: https://docs.confluent.io/current/multi-dc-replicator/replicator-failover.html