# Single Kafka consumer consuming messages from two different cluster simultaneously

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there any option or configuration which will facilitate a single Kafka consumer to consume messages from two different clusters simultaneously?
While creating producer and consumer, I mention both the clusters as comma-separated. I have been observing the the consumer is consuming messages from a single cluster only.

Please see below the elucidation:
Consumer C1 is configured to listen to the clusters:
Cluster-1: Zookeeper-1 with Broker-1
Cluster-2: Zookeeper-2 with Broker-2

I am looking for a solution wherein the consumer C1 can consume messages from Cluster-1 and Cluster-2 simultaneously.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to consume from two different clusters in Kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457254/how-to-consume-from-two-different-clusters-in-kafka)

Comment: There is some relevance there but it doesn't addresses my query completely. There's is a just a small reference mentioning that it's not possible for a consumer to connect more than one cluster. But is there no way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Consuming data from two or more different clusters is not possible. Any instance of a Kafka consumer can consume messages only from a single Kafka cluster.